# Git Gui not loading

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to launch Git Gui, which it does successfully, however when I do Repository -> Visualise all branch history, nothing loads and I get the following error in my terminal (see below).  I want to know if it is safe to re-install git gui without affecting my git repositories/history etc etc?

Cheers

```
Error in startup script: 2014-05-20 15:11:43.764 osascript[20136:903] Error loading    /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:   dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types,  262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:     no matching architecture in universal wrapper
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
while executing
"exec osascript -e [format {
      tell application "System Events"
        set frontmost of processes whose unix id is %d to true
      end te..."
    invoked from within
"if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "aqua"} {
exec osascript -e [format {
    tell application "System Events"
        set frontmost of processes ..."
(file "/opt/local/bin/gitk" line 11755)
invoked from within
"source $AppMain_source"
(file "/opt/local/share/git-gui/lib/Git Gui.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/AppMain.tcl"    line 24)
```

After further research, and a review to the above question, you can still encounter the error even after a fresh install of Git.  However after updating Macports, the issue was resolved!

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Reinstalling Git will not affect your repository. Everything you need is the local `.git` folder in your project. Git would not delete these folders if you uninstall it. Also a copy of this folder means you have a backup of your entire Git history.

Comment: So do I need to re-install git completely or can I just re-install git gui independently?

Comment: I think it is better to reinstall Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reinstallation of git or git-gui will not alter the existing repositories. How should they anyhow?

Comment: Ok thank you.  I was unsure about the relationship between Git and Git Gui.  However I feel assured that it's safe to re-install just Git GUI

Comment: git gui does not alter git too. It is just another software put on top  of git (which is still the usual cli utilily).

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be caused if a program is installed if/when you install Adobe CS3 or CS4.

The way I resolved was by updating to the newer version of Adobe Unit Types found here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/516/cpsid_51615/attachments/Adobe_Unit_Types.osax.zip

**To Install:**

```
cd /Library/ScriptingAdditions

#backup the original file
sudo cp -r Adobe\ Unit\ Types.osax{,.bak}
sudo cp -r /Path/to/your/new/Adobe\ Unit\ Types.osax .
```

**I got these instructions from here:**

https://blog.iefdev.se/2015/01/gui-for-git-with-gitk-in-os-x/